# Move a field and its value from a master table to its details table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server for my project, but my question seems not vendor-specific.

I have two tables and columns as shown below:

```
Master:
id
ok

Details:
id
master_id
```

Now I need to move the "ok" field and value from the master table to the details table. They look like this:

```
Master:
id
ok (kept for copy of values, but will delete it later)

Details:
id
master_id
ok
```

I created the "ok" field in the Details table. How can I copy its value in the master table to its corresponding records in the details table? Is this the correct statement?

```
update Details set ok = (select ok from Master where master_id = id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have more than one table referenced in a query, you should qualify *all* column references.  Perhaps this will fix whatever problem you are having:

```
update Details
    set ok = (select m.ok
              from Master m
              where details.master_id = m.id
             );
```